# How to raise exception in imported file through flask app in json format python?

Tags: python, flask

I have the flask_app.py which has the exception handling,

```
from flask import abort
@app.errorhandler(404)
def NotFoundError(e):
    return jsonify(error=str(e)), 404

if INDEX_EXTENSION == '':
    abort(404, description="Index Extension cannot be NULL")
```

if I run the app in POSTMAN I get the error message in the POSTMAN Response Body as expected

```
{
    "error": "404 Not Found: Index Extension cannot be NULL"
}
```

I am importing functions from another utils.py inside the flask_app.py, say

```
from utils import loaddata
```

If the function raise an error, I can put the function in a try block inside flask_app.py to pass the error message to POSTMAN,

Without putting the function inside try block, Is it possible to send the exception raised inside the function to POSTMAN as jsonify message instead of HTML format, example, inside the function I have

```
    if len(data) == 0:
        raise Exception('Null Data, Check Data Range')
```

this is passed to the console as "Traceback (most recent call last):........ "and in POSTMAN as

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <title>Exception: Null Data, Check Data Range // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=style.css" type="text/css">
.....
.
.
.
.
```

Is it possible to jsonify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a custom error handler like:

```py
def loaddata():
   messages = []
   # do stuff
   if len(data) == 0:
        messages.append('Null Data, Check Data Range')
   return messages
```

Then in your flask code:

```py
    dofunc = loaddata() # dofunc equals to error messages with the codes in the function being already executed
    # instead of abort
    if len(dofunc) > 0:
        return jsonify({'error': dofunc})
```

Demo code for you to understand!

Comment: But now you have duplicate conditional logic for handling the same condition, so you have to maintain that on both sides of the function (caller and function being called).